# How to Display Product specific to a category with WooCommerce Plugin?

Tags: plugins, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using plugin Woocommerce to do shop online.

I have many categories for example `shoes`, `clothes` and so on. How can I display the products of specific category?

I see such product loops of on the [sample page](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/sample-products-loop/), but I only want show the products of a specific category in my `index.php`.

Comment: can u please tell me where to add this code if you please

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to create a new loop for that. Here's the code I use for displaying products from a specific category on the home page:

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'shoes', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <h2>Shoes</h2>

                <li class="product">    

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                    </a>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: @VanTong Then mark this answer as **the answer:** click the checkmark on the left side.

Comment: Hi Dwaser,I want ask more. If in archive page, I want show all new product. and When I choose specific Category It will show product of that category. Example I have 2 category  Category A and Category B,When I choose A, it will show product of A, and choose B it will show product of B. Please tell me loops. thanks.

Comment: hot show message if there is no products?

Comment: @dwaser Hi, deos the product_cat argument accept an int category id, ie: 40 instead of 'shoes' ? if not, how to make it accept an int category id ? thanks

Comment: @dwaser. looks like that function woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() has been deprecated now. Would get_image() be the equivalent? http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1473-1489. Also, why do you check for a post thumbnail first?

Comment: exicuse me guys, but where to add this code ? i'm a newpie in wordpress but i have a very close deadline. @VanTong

Comment: I am also wondering about the context of this code. Where to put it?

Comment: 1 year late, but you should put this in your template. wp-content/yourtheme/template-name.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    echo $product->get_categories(
        ', ',
        '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:',
        sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ),
        'woocommerce' ) . ' ',
        '.</span>'
    );
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how and why this would solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

You can assign the "Shop" page as default home page. Now all the products will displayed to the home page. I mean `index.php`.

Comment: question was for products of a specific category?

Comment: Please delete this answer, as it has nothing to do with the question.