# Woocommerce: all products of all categories instead products of one category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get all products of category by category name (slug). Сategory has no parents or children. I wrote my code according to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67266/86327). My code:

```
<?php 
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => 'pyvo-v-pliashkah'
];

$products = new WP_Query($args);
wp_reset_query();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products->posts);
?>
```

But instead products of "pyvo-v-plyashkah" category I get all products of all categoryes. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the sample code is that the query is reset before echoing the result.

Instead follow the sample you linked to:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => 'pyvo-v-pliashkah'
);

$products_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// output what you want

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thank you, George, but unfortunately result is the same.

Comment: Maybe disable all your plugins to make sure it is not a conflict with them. If it then works, you know what to do :) Usually the number of plugins is not so important, it is the code-quality of them which is a factor of keeping them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **tax_query**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'pyvo-v-pliashkah'
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you, Pratik Patel, but the result is the same. Perhaps some plug-in interferes. I have a lot of them))